# Bootstrap datepicker close function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to make function call on bootstrap datepicker when user clicks outside of calendar.

When user selects date datepicker closes automatically, same when user clicks outside of the datepicker div, it closes itself.

So my question is how can I understand when its closed? I know there is an event called `onClose` but it only works when page loads

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr3dxj5p/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.on("hide"...` event.

From the docs:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on(picker_event, function(e) {
    // `e` here contains the extra attributes
});
```

For your example... `picker_event` will be `hide`.
Something like:

```
var checkin = $('#date-from').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '+1d',
    weekStart: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
},
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    alert("changed");
}).on('hide', function(ev) { // <-----------
    alert("hide");
});
```

- [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/mr3dxj5p/5/)
- [bootstrap-datepicker events](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#events)
- [bootstrap-datepicker hide event](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#hide)

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation here: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#hide

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('hide', function(e) {
        // `e` here contains the extra attributes
    });
```

Or

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('hide', myFunction);
```

And then create `myFunction`

```
function myFunction(e) {
    // whatever you want :)
}
```

Here is your example with little modify https://jsfiddle.net/mr3dxj5p/6/ here you can see I just change `changeDate` to `hide` to fire alert message